# SQL statement to return limited records

Tags: sql

In a SQL statement, how to return `222`, `555`,`666` order which has `PROFESSIONAL` status `C` and has `OFFER` is `N` and as well as `LIFE` with `STATUS` with `A`

```
ORDER_NO    PRODUCT_CODE    STATUS  OFFER
------------------------------------------
111         PROFESSIONAL    A       NULL
222         PROFESSIONAL    C       N
222         LIFE            A       NULL
333         PROFESSIONAL    A       NULL
444         PROFESSIONAL    A       NULL
555         PROFESSIONAL    C       N
555         LIFE            A       NULL
666         PROFESSIONAL    C       N
666         LIFE            A       NULL
```

Comment: Is that sample table data? Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly. It should be as easy as:

```
select
    ORDER_NO
from
    YOUR_TABLE_NAME
where
    (PRODUCT_CODE = 'PROFESSIONAL' and STATUS = 'C' and OFFER = 'N') or
    (PRODUCT_CODE = 'LIFE' and STATUS = 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select order_no
from t
group by order_no
having sum(case when PRODUCT_CODE = 'PROFESSIONAL' and STATUS = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when PRODUCT_CODE = 'LIFE' and STATUS = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

EDIT:

You can also phrase this as:

```
select order_no
from t
where (PRODUCT_CODE = 'PROFESSIONAL' and STATUS = 'C') or
      (PRODUCT_CODE = 'LIFE' and STATUS = 'A')
group by order_no
having count(*) = 2;
```

(This version assumes no duplicate rows.)

Comment: is there a performance benefit to using this method over the select with parameters identified in the where clause?

Comment: @Hopper . . . This returns what you want.  Just filtering in the `WHERE` does not mandate that both conditions are met for a given `order_no`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a group by with some alternates

```
    Select ORDER_NO
     from table where orderno in
   (222, 555,666) group by ORDER_NO 
        having 
           1=Max(case 
           when productcode 
          ='PROFESSIONAL' AND 
            OFFER ='N' AND
            status ='C' 
             THEN 1 

            WHEN productcode 
          ='LIFE' and
              STATUS='A' 
            THEN 1 

            ELSE
            0
            END)
```